# escape=F kable pdf not compiling

Tags: tables, knitr

I am trying to include `m\\textsubscript{2}` in a column name using `kable`.  When I change `escape=F` to allow this to occur the PDF fails to compile.

Code:

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(table2.1,format="latex",row.names=NA,align="c",escape=T,
      col.names=c("Survey","StationID","Latitude (degrees)",
  "Latitude (minutes)","Longitude (degrees)","Longitude (minutes)","Scallops (number)","Scallops (lbs)","Scallops (baskets)","Scallop density (m\\textsubscript{2})","Nematode Prevalence (%)"),caption="Catch data for the commercial dredge from the VIMS/Industry cooperative surveys completed during May-July 2018.  Nematode prevalence (percentage of scallops sampled at a given station infected with nematodes) is also provided for each station.",longtable = T) %>%

  kable_styling(font_size=8,position="center",latex_options =c("repeat_header", "hold_position"),repeat_header_text="Table 2 continued",repeat_header_method="replace") %>%

  column_spec(3:6,width = "0.50in") %>%
  column_spec(7:9,width = "0.49in") %>%
  column_spec(10:11,width = "0.65in")
```

I can get a PDF to compile with the superscript format using the following code using a fake small dataset:

```
A <- data.frame(round(replicate(11, runif(2)),2))

rownames(A) <- c("Hola\\textsubscript{123}", "Hola\\textsubscript{234}")

kable(A,
             row.names = T,
  col.names=c("Survey","StationID","Latitude (degrees)",
  "Latitude (minutes)","Longitude (degrees)","Longitude (minutes)","Scallops (number)","Scallops (lbs)","Scallops (baskets)","Scallop density (m\\textsuperscript{2})","Nematode Prevalence"),escape = F)%>% 

  kable_styling(font_size=8,position="center",latex_options =c("repeat_header", "hold_position"),repeat_header_text="Table 2 continued",repeat_header_method="replace") %>%

  column_spec(3:6,width = "0.25in") %>%
  column_spec(7:9,width = "0.25in") %>%
  column_spec(10:11,width = "0.65in") 
@
```

My data `table2.1` is generated from R source code.  The structure is:

```
data.frame':    770 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Survey           : Factor w/ 3 levels "CAI_II","MAB",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ StationID        : int  201801001 201801002 201801003 201801004 201801005 201801006 201801007 201801008 201801009 201801010 ...
 $ Latitude_degrees : int  36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 ...
 $ Latitude_minutes : num  31 36.1 36.9 41.1 42.1 ...
 $ Longitude_degrees: int  74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 ...
 $ Longitude_minutes: num  48.9 44.5 46.6 48.8 45.4 ...
 $ Scallop_number   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Scallop_lbs      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Scallops_baskets : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Scallop_density  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Nematode         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

When I try to run the example code I got to work with `table2.1`, the PDF also fails to compile when `escape=F`.  This leads me to think there is something in `table2.1` that is preventing the PDF from compiling, but I'm not sure and looking for advice.  I am suing RStudio and pdfLaTex.